# git flow feature finish <branch> throwing "Fatal: Could not check out branch 'develop'."

Tags: git, git-flow

I asked this on the repo itself, but thought it might hit a wider audience here on SO.

I'm not sure why this is happening on an existing project that I added gitflow to.
When I run: git flow feature finish 
I do get "Switched to branch 'develop'" but then immediately followed by "Fatal: Could not check out branch 'develop'."
I then have to merge the branch manually and delete it.

I tried creating just a test project and I don't seem to get that error.
It seems to only happen with the "feature" option. If I use "release" or "hotfix" so far it has been working.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

UPDATE: seems this no longer works with releases either.

Comment: do you have a develop branch?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, I do get "Switched to branch 'develop'" so it does successfully switch, but fails from there for the merge and branch deletion.

Comment: Check that :
1. A develop branch is on your remote origin
2. A develop branch can be checkout out on your local repository based on this remote
3. You don't have extra work locally on this branch based on the branch on origin (else, pull it).

Comment: @MeuhMeuh I was hoping to not have the develop branch on the remote repo. Are you saying I have to for this to work? I currently have a master and staging branch on the remote.

Comment: Honestly, not sure, but this won't cost you much to have the develop branch in remote. That could be the issue, though. Maybe you can try to push it to your remote, and then, finish - in any case, you can still remove the remote branch later.

Comment: @MeuhMeuh I will give it a try on my next set of changes.

Comment: @MeuhMeuh unfortunately, no change.

Comment: Do you know which command gitflow is trying to do when this error is raised ? Which GIT command is run ?

Comment: @MeuhMeuh I don't. --showcommands shows the initial checkout of develop which seems to be successful since that is the branch I am left on. But I get the "Fatal" message right after. Is there a way to trace it further? -v doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. I have a post-checkout script that had an exit in it that was causing the issue. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution :
-delete the folder ".git"
-git init
-git config --global user.email "your@email.com"
-git config --global user.name "Your name"
-git flow init